# Cumulative sum of counter column

Tags: mysql

Want to retrieve cumulative sum of first column following is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(customer_id) AS entries, DATE(sold_date) as date,
(@cum_sum:=@cum_sum+COUNT(customer_id)) as cumulative 
FROM sold_to 
JOIN (select @cum_sum := 0) B  
WHERE sold_date <= curdate() 
GROUP BY DATE(sold_date) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But result of cumulative sum is same of first column:

Comment: the variable is same on every iteration that why sum is not proper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables and `group by` do not mix very well.  Use a subquery:

```
SELECT date, entries,
       (@cum_sum := @cum_sum + entries) as cumulative 
FROM (SELECT date(sold_date) as date, count(*) as entries
      FROM sold_to 
      WHERE sold_date <= curdate() 
      GROUP BY date(sold_date)
     ) s CROSS JOIN
     (select @cum_sum := 0) params
ORDER BY date
LIMIT 0 , 30 ;
```

Comment: i dont have entries coulmn in my database first i am calculating counter from customer_Id